# How to set combobox value?

Tags: combobox, xpages

I need to determine the value to be displayed in the menu according to the logged-in user.
If there are Ariel, Austin, Jennifer and Ryan in the menu, when I log in as Ariel, the menu will not show Ariel, there will only be Austin, Jennifer and Ryan.
How to achieve this requirement?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zgja3.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ym2D1.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the current logged-in user name with

```js
var username = session.createName(session.getEffectiveUserName()).getCommon()
```

and remove the name from the list of users.

Example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core">
    <xp:comboBox id="comboBox1">
        <xp:selectItems>
            <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                var names = new java.util.ArrayList();
                names.add("Ariel A");
                names.add("Austin B");
                names.add("Jennifer C");
                names.add("Ryan D");
                var username = session.createName(session.getEffectiveUserName()).getCommon();
                names.remove(username);
                return names;
            }]]></xp:this.value>
        </xp:selectItems>
    </xp:comboBox>
</xp:view>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers !!!!!
I already tried the method you provided and it did what I wanted!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to bind the available selection to a JavaScript function or a managed bean. It returns an array (JS) or collection (Java). Inside the function you can do the needful based on the user